# Yii2 filter Sum data in GridView

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I'm trying display and filter data which I got via SQL SUM operator.
I have 2 table employee and department. Table employee contains department_id filed and salary filed. I need display all department and total SUM salary for every department.
I followed this [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/679/filter-sort-by-summary-data-in-gridview-yii-2-0/), but GridView does not  display any data.
Here is action:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new DepartmentFrontendSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    return $this->render('index',
        [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,

        ]
    );
}
```

Model:

```
class DepartmentFrontendSearch extends DepartmentFrontend

public $employee_count;
public $salary;


public function rules() {
    return [

        [['employee_count','salary','name'], 'safe']
    ];
}

public function search($params) {

    $query = DepartmentFrontend::find();
    $subQuery = Employee::find()
        ->select('department_id, SUM(salary) as salary_amount')
        ->groupBy('department_id');
    $query->leftJoin(['salarySum' => $subQuery], 'salarySum.department_id = id');

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
    $dataProvider->setSort([
        'attributes' => [
            'name',
            'salary'
        ]
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name]);
    $query->andWhere(['salarySum.salary_amount' => $this->salary]);
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

GRID:

```
   echo GridView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'filterModel' => $searchModel,
   'columns' => [
       ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
       'salary_amount',
       'employee_count',
       'name',

   ],
```

]);

So, can anybody tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Please update your question and add the gridview code  too

Answer (score 0):

If You need  a filter for the alias salary_amount  you should add a specific var for this (do the fact salary_amount is an alias for sum(salary) the var $salary is not useful)

```
public $employee_count;
public $salary;
public $salary_amount;
```

otherwise use salary as alias too

the  in your filter you are using

```
$query->andWhere(['salarySum.salary_amount' => $this->salary]);
```

But salary_amount is the result of an aggregation so you should use      `having(SUM(salary) = $this->salary_amount)`

```
 $query->having('SUM(salary) = ' . $this->salary_amount);
```

Comment: Thank for replay, but it doesn't work. The main thing that all data do not display - for example, I have 3 departments and 3 employees which belong to 2 departments, but in grid display the only department which not has any employee

Comment: Looking at your gridview you have 'salary_amount',  'employee_count', 'name',   but in yoiur select you have only salary_amount .. you should add the others two column in select . (and with the correct alias) . otherwise how do you obtain these dala ?